# Excel VBA - Populating userform listbox from sql server

Tags: arrays, sql-server, excel, vba

Im trying to display the data from SQL Server to my userform listbox but it should have only show distinct value (not duplicating) currently salvaging the code i used in listview but i cant get it right, can someone help me please sorry im still learning. Thanks in advance. Here's my code below.

```
Private Sub LOB_List()
On Error GoTo ERR_Handler
    Dim sql As String
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Records As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim RecCount As Long
    
    
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    
    con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=10.206.88.119\BIWFO;" & _
                          "Initial Catalog=TESTDB;" & _
                          "Uid=user; Pwd=password1;"
                          
    sql = "select distinct lob from data_test"
    
    rst.Open sql, con, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
    
    Records = rst.GetRows
    
    RecCount = rst.RecordCount
    
   
    For i = 0 To rst.Fields.count - 1
      
    Next i
    
    rst.Close
    con.Close

    With ListBox1
    
           
        Dim li As ListBox
        
        
        For i = 0 To RecCount - 1
            Set li = .ListBox.List(, , Records(0, i))
            For j = 1 To UBound(Records)
                If Not IsNull(Records(j, i)) Then li.ListSubItems.Add , , Records(j, i)
                
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
    
ERR_Handler:

    Select Case Err.Number
    
        Case 0
        Case Else
        
            MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, Err.Number
            
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You're adding the items twice, once by assigning  `.List = Records` and again in a loop.

Comment: I've removed the `.List = Records`, im having trouble with the `ListItems` it said that "Variable not defined"

Comment: Did you remove all the listbox-related code from your post?

Comment: Yeah i edited my post and im totally lost :(

Comment: A good start would be to put back the code you removed.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, already put back the code.

Comment: https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/vba-macros/videos/vba-ado-net-recordsets/recordset-to-listbox/ shows one way to do it.

Comment: I got it!!!! Thanks a lot sir!! *sending love